# IPC - Ways for not consuming CPU

Tags: c, pthreads, ipc, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am writing in C a program with using Producer-Consumer.

I have a process comunicating with N consumers via a shared memory. In order to achieve this I am using semaphores. However my process needs to wait uncertain time for a consumer to send some data.

Is there any way to achieve this besides `sleep(1)` and keep checking for new data?
In worst case this could lead to 1 second delay (process sleeps and consumer writes right after sleep).

I am using 1 set of 2 semaphores (1 semaphore for a priority queue between consumers and 1 semaphore for main process - consumer in critical section).

Comment: Which API are you using for the semaphores?

Comment: By API meaning platform? If so, Unix.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of semaphores that they offer a blocking wait function?

Comment: @user2147971 I guess that answers it. It probably means that the API you're using is [POSIX threads (pthreads)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads) :)

Comment: see man page for function sem_timedwait